Alfa romeo 147 hard gear strange engine noise
I have an alfa romeo 147 2007, lately the gear got so hard,and i also noticed some oil on the ground where i park the car, and today i noticed when i accelerate the engine is making a strange noise like its pulling air into the engine, a very strange noise.
I checked the engine oil and the water all good.
What could be the issue? The gear oil? Could it cause such a noise in the engine?
Thank you

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by "lately the gear got so hard"? Is it having problems shifting? Could you explain a little better what kind of noise are you hearing? Does the noise change pitch with the engine or the speed of the vehicle? Where exactly in relation to the vehicle is the oil (front/middle/rear)? Can you look under the vehicle and see where it might be coming from?

Im facing problems shifting the gear, on first and second gear mostly and the reverse. The noise i hear is when i accelerate at a certain level or higher the engine makes noise like its pulling air inside the engine but it feels like its useless air, the doesnt get in. Just like the engine pulling air, more i accelerate the noise goes louder.
